# Save a memory image (such as Uint8list) as image file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, uint8array, uint8list

I have some Uint8lists and I want to save them as jpg files.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `File` class from `dart.io` has methods to save that list

Comment: I don't wanna save the list

Comment: *"and I wanna save them in storage"* - so what do you want to do actually?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation! edited now.

Comment: question is hard to understand. explain your question better

Comment: Is it understandable now?!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By 'storage', do you mean write to a file? You don't really need "flutter" to do this. Just use the libraries provided by dart. Here is an example of downloading my gravatar which you can get as `Uin8List` and then saving it to a file.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  http.get('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e944138e1114aefe4b08848a46465589').then((response) {
    Uint8List bodyBytes = response.bodyBytes;
    File('my_image.jpg').writeAsBytes(bodyBytes);
  });
}
```

Comment: 'my_image.jpg', where it will be stored? How can we set specific folder to store the file?

Comment: You can save to a specific path like
`final dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final myImagePath = dir!.path + "/myimg.png";
File imageFile = File(myImagePath);
if(! await imageFile.exists()){
  imageFile.create(recursive: true);
}
imageFile.writeAsBytes(image);`

Comment: @djalmafreestyler - it will be stored at the "current working directory" which you ran the program.

Comment: Note that this only works because the Uint8List is already storing image data in JPEG format. As such, the question doesn't answer how to save RAW image bytes (which is what I came here for), as these would need to be encoded as PNG or JPEG or similar, first. I believe the missing step here is:
`ByteData byteData =
await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();`
where `image` is from the `dart:ui` package.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and short solution of your problem. Use this line in your code as I did:

```
"SettableMetadata(contentType: "image/jpeg"),"
```

Code:

```
 if (kIsWeb) {
         await ref.putData(
          await imageFile.readAsBytes(),
           SettableMetadata(contentType: "image/jpeg"),
         );
         url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
         }
```

Comment: your solution make another question, what is ref?